# Delete last line from multiple docx files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, python-docx

I want to delete text of multiple docx file using python language.

Let's say the contents of a file are:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
```

I want to delete the very last line only i.e. `This is line 4`.

I've tried many code but getting errors.

Try 1:

```
with open(r"FILE_PATH.docx", 'r+', errors='ignore') as fp:
    # read an store all lines into list
    lines = fp.readlines()
    # move file pointer to the beginning of a file
    fp.seek(0)
    # truncate the file
    fp.truncate()

    # start writing lines except the last line
    # lines[:-1] from line 0 to the second last line
    fp.writelines(lines[:-1])
```

Above code runs with 0 errors but getting some loss of data in the docx file.

See the relevant screenshots [here](https://postimg.cc/5YV5SmHw) and [here](https://postimg.cc/HJC8qkpm).

Answer (score 1):

You will not get the correct lines from a `docx` using that method, a `docx` is not the like a text file. (If you use your current method on a `txt` file it will work).

Do this and you can see what you are removing:

```
with open(r"FILE_PATH.docx", 'r+', errors='ignore') as fp:
    # read an store all lines into list
    lines = fp.readlines()
    print(lines[-1]) # or print(lines) to see all the lines
```

You are not removing `This is line 4` you are removing a part of the `docx` file.

Although there are ways to read a docx without additional libraries, using something like `docx2txt` or `textract` might be easier.

There are other questions in stack overflow that address how to read and modify a `docx`, take a look and you will find a way to adapt your code if a `docx` is still what you want to work with.

Comment: Got my answer bro. So, I've just edited the string I'm passing to docx file with a line of code - 
    ```result = text[: text.rfind('\n')]```